# Is the SDP a=crypto attribute relevant when DTLS-SRTP is used?

Tags: tls, webrtc

The a=crypto attribute in RFC 4568 has a separate section 9.2. for SRTP "Crypto" Attribute Grammar.  What it basically includes is a list of attribute values required for encrypting media (crypto suite, method, session params, keys, MKI...).

However, DTLS-SRTP also does the same (RFC 5764 - SRTP Extension for DTLS). So, is it correct to say that where DTLS-SRTP is used, the a=crypto: attribute is not used. For example, does webRTC offer-answer SDP use the "a=crypto:" attribute as DTLS-SRTP is a must for webRTC?

Informational [RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-rtcweb-sdp-11) "SDP for webRTC" also does not throw any light on this issue.

Please clarify.